# How to work with decimals ( multiplying, dividing, etc.)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

So my code takes a decimal such as 230.3284 and splits it in to 230 and .3284. Is there anyway I can take that '.3284' and divide it by 2 or do I have to rewrite my whole code

```
value = 230.3284
x = value.split('.')    #x[0] is the whole number, x[1] is the decimal
decimal = '.' + x[1]
return int(decimal) / 2
```

which returns

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '.125'
```

Comment: Show your code so far.

Comment: What code? You forget to add it

Comment: Is it a news? Add your code.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this:

```
value = 230.3284
return (value-int(value))/2
```

The `int()` function floors the float it takes as argument and returns it as an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

You are converting the decimals to an `integer` value, meaning you're basically losing all information stored in them since it's only the decimal part of the number.

Try to convert it to a `float` value.

Comment: god bless your soul

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one:

```
>>>s = 230.3284
>>>i, d = divmod(s, 1)
>>> i
230.0
>>> d
0.3283999999999878
>>> d/2
0.1641999999999939
```